# How to connect google colab with localhost running docker image?

Tags: python, docker, localhost, google-colaboratory

[Errors while connecting with localhost link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIk1Q.png)

I am trying to run meilisearch in colab. I run meiliSearch in docker and I have a localhost link http://localhost:7700/. I have tried both http://localhost:7700/ as well as http://192.168.43.57:7700. But I am getting error. Although I can connect with my local jupyter notebook. Any solution?

Comment: Please add relevant code, errors, etc. as text to your post.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the full screen but most likely the error in colab is because it is hosted on remote server by Google research where as the http://localhost:7700/ is on your local system.

You can't connect them using http://localhost:7700/.
And if you have also used your machines ip address, that is http://192.168.43.57:7700 and can't connect then did you first expose your port number 7700 to internet?

You will need to expose your local machine and some ports(7700) using different services which provide the required.

You can read the following article on how to setup tunneling service or ssh to expose the local development on internet.

[Medium Article on How to expose a local development server to the Internet](https://medium.com/botfuel/how-to-expose-a-local-development-server-to-the-internet-c31532d741cc)

Or use this directly. [Use local tunnel](https://localtunnel.github.io/www/)

Comment: Thanks, but local tunnel is down right now... https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started/setup and it worked

Answer (score 0):

*Please Follow below steps to connect docker image as a local runtime for Google-colab:*

1. Create a **Dockerfile** and paste the below contents

```html
# Jupyter data science image including all packages, you may change the image as per your requirements
FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook:latest

# Colab step 1
RUN pip install jupyter_http_over_ws \
    && jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_http_over_ws

# Expose the port for host network
EXPOSE 8888

# Colab step 2
CMD ["jupyter","notebook","--NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com'","--allow-root","--port","8888","--NotebookApp.port_retries=0","--ip","0.0.0.0"]
```

2. Build the **colab-runtime** image by running the command in the terminal from the same directory where **Dockerfile** is saved

```html
docker build -t colab-runtime .
```

An Image **colab-runtime:latest** will be created.

3. Fire the command in terminal to run image as a container

   Note:- Replace {your_host_path} with your host system path. e.g ***/home/mujassim/work:/home/jovyan/work***

- Do not change /home/jovyan/work path.

```html
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -v {your_host_path}:/home/jovyan/work colab-runtime:latest
```

After Running the above command, A URL is provided by the container in the logs.

4. Paste that URL in colab runtime by replacing only **127.0.0.1** or **container_id** with **localhost**
5. If you dont want to run step no. 3 again and again to start the jupyter server then follow the commands listed below:

   - Note down the *container id* and *name* of currently running jupyter server by: ***docker container ls***
   - Stop the container for a while: ***docker container stop {container_id}***
   - Rename the container : ***docker rename {old_container_name} colab-runtime***
   - Now you may run the following commands to start or stop the local runtime for google-colab: ***docker container start colab-runtime*** or ***docker container stop colab-runtime***

Note: You have to provide new URL each time in google colab.

Answer (score 0):

I could connect my Docker-container running on my localhost with google colab with the help of ngrok. With the help of ngrok you can create a url under which your localhost is publicly available. I followed [this tutorial](https://ngrok.com/docs/getting-started/).

**First you need to install ngrok.**

For MacOS, use HomeBrew:

```
brew install ngrok/ngrok/ngrok
```

For Linux, use Apt:

```
curl -s https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com/ngrok.asc | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ngrok.asc >/dev/null && \
  echo "deb https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com buster main" | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ngrok.list && \
  sudo apt update && sudo apt install ngrok
```

For Windows, use Chocolatey:

```
choco install ngrok
```

**Then set up ngrok with your Authentification Token**

For this you need to sign-up [here](https://ngrok.com) for a ngrok account. There you will obtain a Authentification Token. Then run the following command

```
ngrok config add-authtoken TOKEN
```

and  replace "TOKEN" with your actual token.

**Now you  can start ngrok by running the following command.**

```
ngrok http PORTNUMBER
```

Replace "PORTNUMBER" with the port of your localhost you want to connect  to.

Now you will obtain a url under which your localhost  service is publicly available. The url will look somewhat like https://84c5df439d74.ngrok-free.dev

**Since the whole world can access this URL, we need to secure it quickly.**

Stop your ngrok process and run

```
ngrok http PORTNUMBER --basic-auth 'username:password'
```

**Now you can use this URL in google colab to connect to localhost**

In my case I connected google-colab with a docker container running elasticsearch like this:

```
es = Elasticsearch(
    hosts=[{
        'host': 'c04c-89-128-141-226.ngrok-free.app',
        'port': 443,
        'scheme': 'https',
    }]
```

Of  course this will change depending on your use case.